# MySQL Trigger AFTER UPDATE execution is extremely slow for a table of 50000 rows

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have written a MySQL AFTER UPDATE Trigger to UPDATE records of Table-B belonging to Database-B whenever a row of Table-A belonging to another Database-A to is UPDATED.

Where Table-A and Table-B consists of same columns and structure, but belong to two different Databases. Namely, Database-A and Database-B

This simple operation is taking more than 20 mins time to traverse 50000+ rows of Table-B. This is extremely slowly.

Please help me with where I'm going wrong with the Trigger. Or is there any way I can reduce the time taken to execute the Trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_data

    AFTER UPDATE ON Database-A.TABLE-A

    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (some condition) 
            THEN
                UPDATE Database-B.TABLE-B
                SET 
                    col_1=-2,
                    col_2=NEW.col_2                 
                WHERE col_3=NEW.col_3 and col_4=NEW.col_4;              

            ELSE
                UPDATE Database-B.TABLE-B
                SET 
                    col_1=-2,
                    col_2=NEW.col_2  
                WHERE col_5=NEW.col_5 and col_6=NEW.col_6;                                

            END IF;                     
        END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I expect the execution time of 2 to 3 mins, but the actual execution time is more than 20 Mins.

Answer (score 0):

be user you have a composite  index  on tbale

```
Database_B.TABLE_B   columns(col_3,col_4)
```

and

```
Database_B.TABLE_B   columns(col_5,col_6)
```

(And youn should not use  notation with minus sign between object  name,  this notation require  backtics)

Comment: Just for illustration I've used the "-" symbol for the Database , Table and Columns name.